# app.get with parameter won't render html

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express 4, app.get with parameter won't render the view.

//user.js

```
exports.renderView = function(req, res){
   res.render('index');
}

//route.js

app.get('/verify' , renderView);
```

// This renders view, it looks for views in app/views folder.

```
app.get('/verify/:id' , renderView);
```

// But this won't render the view, it looks for views in app/views/verify folder.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried telling express where to look for these views like so...

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Comment: Yeah, I did this, as app.get without parameter works

Comment: This is how i do my route files: for user i would have:  var router = express.Router(); router.get('/userlist', function(req, res) { //return json object } then in a global js file i write code to view that json data in a specific view

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're doing it like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/verify', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index');
});

router.get('/verify/:id', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

You have to make a function for both routes

Well, I guess you don't have to but if you plan on providing different functionality for the route with a param I highly suggest it.

If you're calling app.get without app being injected into your module or something then it just doesn't exist, the proper way to route is the example I gave above